# Unable to use Or filter in cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to use the `or` Filter in my NodeJS function, but I cannot find the `Filter` class to import. My firebase-admin package version is `^11.7.0`. I am referring to this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries

I have tried this, but the class `Filter` is undefined

```js
const {Filter} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
```

How can I use the `or` filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the exact issue with `firebase-admin` version `11.7.0`. I believe this could be bug in the version. I was able to use `Filter` successfully with `11.5.0` or `11.9.0` versions. Try to upgrade or degrade the version using below command.

```
npm i firebase-admin@VERSION
```

***Note: The issue is fixed in the [`11.9.0` version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node)***